# Google crawler is drawning resources from my wordpress website by scanning a huge quantity of unexisting pages

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

Recently i give a look to my search console after a notification of my provider.

It told me that google is crawling a huge quantity of unexisting web pages (that result in 404 errors).

I see on my search console reported 325.599 unindexed pages (all with 404). The website is really simple with a little number of pages/posts (about 200).
These pages are not really existing and i don't know how the crawler is getting them.

Here are some example addresses:

```
https://website.it/7113dtlsb0ba0d7nt9437213
https://website.it/215dtls972d85fdfs4c7bb11f
https://website.it/constant.php?27847qhnya9bcf0zyaa24fd
```

All those link are unexisting and google is not reporting a referral, so i cannot know the source.
Also i searched on the internet to see if those are referred somewhere, i found nothing.

Have anyone got my same issue?

It there a tool that can help me to scan my WP installation to find this broken links?

Comment: This isn't really related to PHP. Probably better on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. Do you have a `robots.txt` on your site? Do you have a webmaster account in Google? You should be able to tell Google to go slower, and/or to not visit certain pages. I don't see a pattern above but also looks pseudo. You also need to clarify if they are `broken links` or non-existent links.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @user3783243. I'm sorry, i'm a newbie on Stack overflow and may be i'm doing something wrong. Btw I don't know what you mean with "related to php". I specified these tags: "wodpress" "seo" "google-search-console" that i think are in topic with my issue. About the issue, i'm talking about non-existent links. The problem is that i have no idea of how those links are catched by the crawler. I am investigating further, the issue seems related to a caching plug-in (lite-speed), but i'm not sure at moment.

Comment: PHP was originally tagged, maybe SO did it. I edited the post to remove it. Do you have a robot.txt file on the server? Do you have sitemaps submitted to Google?